# Can I still get a specific ending in Witcher 3 although I have the condition for a "better" one?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm almost at the end of the game.
I've read that

> bringing Ciri to the emperor

is a main condition for

> her becoming the empress.

However, I would prefer my ending to

> have Ciri become a Witcher.

Is this still possible? FYI, on the other possible options I

> had a snowball fight with her and refused Emhyr's monetary reward.

Answer (score 4):

This actually depends on five conditions, which include:

- taking Ciri to Emperor Emhyr
- letting Ciri speak alone to the lodge
- having the snowball fight with Ciri
- accompanying Ciri to the grave of the man in Skellige
- turning down Emperor Emhyr's payment

If you manage 3-4 of these, you should get the second ending (Witcheress).

5/5 will result in empress ending, fewer will result in the other ending.

Comment: Having had a quick Google, I'm slightly less sure. I thought I'd taken Ciri to see the Emperor and then got the Witcheress ending in my first play, but this page suggests that's not possible: https://www.vg247.com/2015/05/28/the-witcher-3-how-to-get-the-best-ending/ Additionally, I got the condition count wrong. Bah - shouldn't write answers on my phone. I'm tempted to remove my answer, based on that page.

Comment: this page provides some new evidence. I'm very close to checking for myself (some time in the coming weeks). http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/702760-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/71946836

Comment: Could you extend your answer that Nilfgard also needs to win the war (e.g. Djikstra must not have rule over Redania)? I'd love to accept your answer after you do, because this is precisely how I achieve the ending despite fulfilling all 5 criteria you listed.